# Converting a pandas column to datetime with inconsistent format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['abc', 'abc', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'cd'], 'col2':['2020-02-01 12:04:59', '2020.09.29.12.04.59', '2020.09.28.16.32.21', '2020-02-01 16:04:59', '2020-05-01 11:04:59']})
df

    col1    col2
0   abc 2020-02-01 12:04:59
1   abc 2020.09.29.12.04.59
2   xyz 2020.09.28.16.32.21
3   xyz 2020-02-01 16:04:59
4   cd  2020-05-01 11:04:59
```

The col2 values are not consistent(different format) and that's why I cannot convert it to datetime format.

I used `df['col2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col2'])` code to convert that column to datetime but `getting ParserError: Unknown string format: 2020.09.29.12.04.59`error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove all the non digit characters:

```
df['col2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col2'].str.replace('\D',''))
```

Output:

```
  col1                col2
0  abc 2020-02-01 12:04:59
1  abc 2020-09-29 12:04:59
2  xyz 2020-09-28 16:32:21
3  xyz 2020-02-01 16:04:59
4   cd 2020-05-01 11:04:59
```